# Invert colors in system tray icon upon click in Qt4?

Tags: qt, macos, qt4, system-tray

Basically I want to invert the colors of my systrayicon only osx app when it is clicked (as normal on Mac apps), as is default behavior on mac apps. How would I do this now when aboutToHide() isn’t supported on Mac?

Can I code around it somehow? Using qt 4.7.3

Answer (score 2):

I hawen't written for mac but try to catch click event and manually set icon with inverted colors...

```
void <YourClass>::onTrayIconActivated(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason reason)
{
    if(reason==QSystemTrayIcon::Trigger)
    {
        <Your tray object>->setIcon(<Icon with inverted colors>);
    }
}
```

connect it to your trayIcon's signal `activated()`

if default behavior on mac is to invert icon colors back, you may do it with timer or something similar.

Comment: That is the same solution that I used. But using a timer felt so tacky that I ended up porting it over to cocoa.

Answer (score 1):

Can you set a selected state pixmap for your icon, e.g. `myIcon->addPixmap(":/systray-selected.png", QIcon::Selected);` ?